# how to add 3rd party jars in cloud foundry server

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am new to Cloud Foundry, I created an account, and created a Java application.
Now I need to add 3rd party jar and lib to tomcat/lib folder and add lib to environment variable of that server.

Is this possible in cloud foundry?

Thanks

Comment: I think you would be better off asking this in their forums: http://support.cloudfoundry.com/categories/11129-Cloud-Foundry-Forums

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are trying to do, instead of deploying your app as a Java app, you will have to do a standalone deployment along with your custom Tomcat.
Take a look here for explanation : http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/11/running-standalone-web-applications-on-cloud-foundry/

Let me know if you need any other help.

Thanks,
- Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new War file for your application after normally adding the new 3rd party jar and then redeploy the application. That will update your application on cloudfoundry.

Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Thanks,
- Hitesh

Comment: my case is different I have to add 3rd party jar to tomcat/lib folder not in aplication/lib folder also I need to add some lib file (.dll,.so,.lib) to tomcat/lib folder and add that to path so I can asses that lib functionality in my application.

Comment: How would you add a 3rd party jar file for deployment to cf?